# Application is not deploying on jboss 7 server

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, ibm-mq, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate an application which uses IBM MQ7.0 to IBM MQ9.2. This Application built using Java 7, Apache camel, and Google Guice frameworks.

When I try to install the application in JBOSS 7 server, I m getting below exceptions

```
03:13:26,389 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/purchase-app]] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.purchase.ws.module.GuiceServletConfigImpl: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnectionFactory
        at com.purchase.ws.module.GuiceServletConfigImpl.prepareInterlineJMSConfiguration(GuiceServletConfigImpl.java:984) [classes:]
        at com.purchase.ws.module.GuiceServletConfigImpl.setUpCamelContextAndRouter(GuiceServletConfigImpl.java:233) [classes:]
        at com.purchase.ws.module.GuiceServletConfigImpl.contextInitialized(GuiceServletConfigImpl.java:144) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory from [Module "deployment.purchase-app-20.12.1.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.2.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.2.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.2.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.2.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.2.GA-redhat-1]
        ... 11 more

03:13:26,401 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Error listenerStart
03:13:26,401 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Context [/purchase-app] startup failed due to previous errors
03:13:26,487 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) Shutting down the routes.......
03:13:26,492 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Apache Camel 2.10.4 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
03:13:26,522 INFO  [org.apache.camel.management.ManagementStrategyFactory] (MSC service thread 1-3) JMX enabled.
03:13:26,524 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Apache Camel 2.10.4 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.031 seconds. Uptime not started.
03:13:26,524 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-3) Route shutdown completed.......
```

I am able to run the simple java program to place the message in the queue with both v7 and v9 ibm mq jars.
Did not face any compilation issues. Using Maven to build the application.

I am not sure if any dependency is missing? Here is the pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Camel Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Using Maven to build the application as war file. Below is the pom extract

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingIncludes>
                        **/hibernate-core*.jar,
                        **/hibernate-jpa-2.1*.jar,
                        **/*.class,
                        **/*.html,
                        **/*.xml,
                        **/*.wsdl,
                        **/*.properties,
                        **/log4j-rolling-appender*.jar,
                        **/guice*.jar,
                        **/javax.inject*.jar,
                        **/aopalliance*.jar,
                        **/jersey*.jar,
                        **/jersey-client*.jar,
                        **/jersey-core*.jar,
                        **/jersey-guice*.jar,
                        **/jersey-json*.jar,
                        **/jersey-server*.jar,
                        **/infinispan-core*.jar,
                        **/commons*.jar,
                        **/marshalling-api*.jar,
                        **/river*.jar,
                        **/jackson*.jar,
                        **/apache-log4j-extras*.jar,
                        **/log4j*.jar,
                        **/asm*.jar,
                        **/axis2*.jar,
                        **/axiom*.jar,
                        **/XmlSchema*.jar,
                        **/xmlbeans*.jar,
                        **/httpcore*.jar,
                        **/neethi*.jar,
                        **/camel-core*.jar,
                        **/camel-jms*.jar,
                        **/camel-stream*.jar,
                        **/com.ibm.mq.allclient*.jar,
                        **/jms*.jar,
                        **/fscontext*.jar,
                        **/providerutil*.jar,
                        **/connector*.jar,
                        **/spring-aop-*.jar,
                        **/spring-beans-*.jar,
                        **/spring-context-*.jar,
                        **/spring-context-support-*.jar,
                        **/spring-core-*.jar,
                        **/spring-expression-*.jar,
                        **/spring-framework-bom-*.jar,
                        **/spring-jdbc-*.jar,
                        **/spring-jms-*.jar,
                        **/spring-parent-*.jar,
                        **/spring-tx-*.jar,
                        **/spring-web-*.jar,
                        **/spring-webmvc-*.jar,
                        **/ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.jar,
                        **/ocrs*.jar,
                        **/cxf-*.jar,
                        **/xmlschema-*.jar,
                        **/camel-cxf*.jar,
                        **/camel-spring*.jar,
                        **/camel-*.jar,
                        **/jetty*.jar
                    </packagingIncludes>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <projectVersion>${project.version}</projectVersion>
                            <configurationnamespace>${project.artifactId}</configurationnamespace>
                            <applicationversion>${project.version}</applicationversion>
                            <config_path>${config_path}</config_path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

In the above plugin tags code, I had replaced the IBM MQ7.0 jar versions with com.ibm.mq.allclient*.jar file.

If I extract the deployable war file, I could see the allclient jar sitting inside the 'WEB-INF/lib' folder.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you build the deployable (war, ear)?

Comment: updated the description, to include the build information

Comment: Get rid of `**/connector*.jar`, this is no longer part of IBM MQ v8.0 and later.